# Що значить і звідки походить сталий вираз "дати на горіхи"?

Tags: словосполучення, семантика

**Дати на горіхи** - це старовжитній автентичний фразеологізм, що означає cучасною мовою "провести навчально-пояснювальну бесіду". Найчастіше його можна зустріти в українській літературі XVIII-XIX cт. До синонімічного ряду також можна записати "дати прочухана" або "виписати чарівного пендюля" та ін.

На жаль, пошук по тлумачним словникам будь-якої зрозумілої відповіді про походження цього сталого виразу не дає. Запрошую шановне панство-спільноту допомогти розв'язати це запитання.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Фразеологічний словник](http://slovopedia.org.ua/49/53395/357063.html) окрім горіхів наводить приклади, де роль "горіхів" виконують "кислички", "бублики", "риба", "гостинці", "галушки"і навіть [кабачки](https://uk.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B4%D1%96%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8F_%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%96%D1%85%D0%B8).

Отже, можна сказати, що цей вираз означає "Отримаєш що заробив (і зможеш витратити свій заробіток на горіхи, кислички, тощо)". А оскільки з контексту зрозуміло що зробив шкоду, отже зрозуміло, що і винагорода буде негативна (щодо "бесіди" не впевнений, швидше "будеш покараний").

Чому з усіх варіантів саме горіхи використовуються найчастіше відповісти не можна, хіба що висловити припущення, що саме цей варіант винагороди найбільш стилістично нейтральний.

Answer (score 1):

Інше пояснення таке, що раніше горіхи були поширеними ласощами. Якщо діти пустували та дуріли, то щоб утихомирити їх їм погрожували — «Дістанеться вам на горіхи», тобто, насправді або не дістанеться, або й того гірше. Як вказав Artemix це могли бути й інші лагомини.